# Migrating existing authentication to has_secure_password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my application, I have two different user accounts. The old account type was using a custom built authentication system. The newer one implements has_secure_password. Now I'm ready to move the old account type to the same system. In the database, that user type has a hashed_password column.

I have it working so that creating new users works, and they can login just fine on the new system. The problem is that I need existing users to be able to migrate their passwords from the hashed_password to password_digest. What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Is it OK with you that you're going to have to set a new password for each user (rather than their current password)?

Comment: @JesseWolgamott, probably not. It's an application in wide use, and I get the feeling my boss would not like that.

Comment: You're gonna have a hard time. You cannot decrypt the hash, and the 2 auth system use different hashing algorithms. In short: you can't do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, but you'll have to juggle a bit. Let's say you've used MD5 to hash passwords before you wanted to migrate. Make sure you have made a backup before you migrate :) Add a boolean column `migrated_password` to the database, default true. In your migration, do something like `User.update_all(migrated_password: false)` for existing users.

Use the current MD5 hashes as input for the `has_secure_password` function. Alter your login code to handle two paths, depending on the value of the  migrated_password column. If the password is migrated (or the user registered after the migration), you use has_secure_password straight out of the box.

If it isn't, you hash the password with MD5 before feeding it to the `authenticate` method. If the login is successful, change the password of that user with the input password from the params and update the migrated_password column to false (wrap those two actions in a transaction).

After a certain amount of time you can delete the the migrated_password column and the migration code, and let users use your password reset functionality if they still need access but haven't migrated in time.